# expected identifier or )

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have a project that contains several header files, when the project imported into Xcode and compiled, on of the header files caused the following error:

```
expected identifier or )
../../../projjack/Lumbroot/xx.h
```

would you please suggest some solution to fix this issue, there are similar questions about solving the same error, but it does not address my issue.

Comment: How can you think we would be able to solve the problem without having the involved code?

Answer (score 0):

> also,why do you think I receive such an error despite the path to the header file does not contain ")" sign?

Because the error is in what is being *included* not in the file name.

> would you please suggest some solution to fix this issue

In Xcode open the file reporting the error then select the menu item `Product > Perform Action > Preprocess "<file>"`. This will produce you a "flat" view of the file with all files included and all processing tokens expanded. The view will contain lines starting with `#` which indicate the files the various lines originally came from. In this view locate the point at which Xcode shows the error in the original file and then examine the lines preceding that point. You should locate what is causing your issue. You can then open the original file containing the error and fix it.

HTH